# can't download apps through unity

Tags: unity

I am unable to buy apps using ubuntu. I tried to download full circle magazine through Unity in Ubuntu 12.04 and received an error

```
 "Problem occurred while loading the URL https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/tos/plain/
Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()"
```

This happened on other occasions too and it seems that it is related to buying apps. Installing applications and software through unity has not been a problem. I don't have a proxy.

Comment: No I do not use a proxy

Comment: I checked my network settings and indeed it appears that somehow a proxy was being used. Disabled it and now everything seems to work OK. Should have thought of this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a proxy, you must have set it somewhere. Check in System Settings > Network > Proxy. Check the entries if they are correct or disable them if you don't need a proxy.